# insertion in database from ContentValues not working

Tags: android, sqlite

```
private EditText etWord;
private EditText etTranslation;
private Switch engUsrb;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik; // class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ContentValues values;

private String word;
private String translation;
private boolean eng;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);

    ////////// findViewById //////////
    etWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    etTranslation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTranslation);
    engUsrb = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.engUsrb);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabSaveWord);

    word = etWord.getText().toString();
    translation = etTranslation.getText().toString();
    eng = engUsrb.isChecked();

    dbRjecnik = new RjecnikDB(this);
    db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();

    ////////// Adding to database //////////
    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_WORD, word);
    values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_TRANSLATION, translation);
    values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_ENGUSRP, eng);

    ///////// Floating Action Button Listener //////////
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db.insert(RjecnikDB.TABLE, null, values);

            etWord.setText("");
            etTranslation.setText("");
            etWord.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

I can't figure out why this make new row in table but it is always null value for both of EditText views.
If I add text tag in EditText in XML e.g. `android:text="default"`, that works, that make new row with value "default" as expected, but obtaining text from EditText views not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving the contents of your edittexts too early before anything is written in them.

Move the `getText().toString()` inside the `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 private EditText etWord;
private EditText etTranslation;
private Switch engUsrb;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

private RjecnikDB dbRjecnik; // class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ContentValues values;

private String word;
private String translation;
private boolean eng;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_word);

    ////////// findViewById //////////
    etWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWord);
    etTranslation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTranslation);
    engUsrb = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.engUsrb);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabSaveWord);

    dbRjecnik = new RjecnikDB(this);
    db = dbRjecnik.getWritableDatabase();

    ///////// Floating Action Button Listener //////////
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            word = etWord.getText().toString();
            translation = etTranslation.getText().toString();
            eng = engUsrb.isChecked();
            ////////// Adding to database //////////
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_WORD, word);
            values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_TRANSLATION, translation);
            values.put(RjecnikDB.COLUMN_ENGUSRP, eng);

            db.insert(RjecnikDB.TABLE, null, values);

            etWord.setText("");
            etTranslation.setText("");
            etWord.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

Don't forgot de close your database after using

Comment: Does this gonna work? 
    `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        db.close();
    }`

Comment: Yes probably beacause with the back press your activity will finish

Comment: The best way when you work with databases is to create a new class with fonctions that handle all your database operations, you can find a lot of example by searching on google